# Problem 12-1 in Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, covering-spaces

Problem 12-1 from *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by Lee:

> Suppose $q_1 : E \to X_1$ and $q_2 : E \to X_2$ are normal coverings. Show that there exists a covering $X_1 \to X_2$ making the obvious diagram commute if and only if $\text{Aut}_{q_1}(E) \subseteq \text{Aut}_{q_2}(E)$.

Lee defines a covering map $q : E \to X$ to be a continuous surjective map such that $E
$ is connected and locally path-connected, and every point of $X$ has an evenly covered neighborhood (a neighborhood $U$ such that $q^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of connected open subsets of $E$, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $q$). $\text{Aut}_{q}(E)$ is the group of homeomorphisms $\varphi: E \to E$ such that $q \circ \varphi = q$. The covering $q$ is normal if $q_*\pi_1(E,e)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,q(e))$ for some $e \in E$.

**The only concern I have with my solution is that I did not use the assumption that $q_2$ is a normal covering, only that it is a covering. Did I miss something, or is this assumption not needed?**

My solution:

Suppose that $q : X_1 \to X_2$ is a covering such that $q \circ q_1 = q_2$. If $\varphi \in \text{Aut}_{q_1}(E)$, then $q_2 \circ \varphi = q \circ q_1 \circ \varphi = q \circ q_1 = q_2$. So $\text{Aut}_{q_1}(E) \subseteq \text{Aut}_{q_2}(E)$.

Suppose now that $\text{Aut}_{q_1}(E) \subseteq \text{Aut}_{q_2}(E)$. If $q_1(e) = q_1(e')$, then there exists some $\varphi \in \text{Aut}_{q_1}(E)$ such that $e = \varphi(e')$ because $q_1$ is a normal covering (Corollary 12.5 - If $q : E \to X$ is a covering map, then $\text{Aut}_{q}(E)$ acts transitively on each fiber if and only if $q$ is a normal covering). Since $\varphi \in \text{Aut}_{q_2}(E)$, we also have $q_2(e) = q_2(\varphi(e')) = q_2(e')$. So $q_2$ respects the identifications made by $q_1$ (as a quotient map), hence descends to a surjective continuous function $q : X_1 \to X_2$ with $q_2 = q \circ q_1$. Now $X_1$ is connected and locally path-connected because $q_1$ is an open quotient map. It remains to show that every point of $X_2$ has a neighborhood evenly covered by $q$.

Fix some $x_0 \in X_2$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x_0$ that is evenly covered by $q_2$. We will show that $U$ is also evenly covered by $q$. Suppose that $U_i, U_j \subseteq E$ are components of $q_2^{-1}(U)$. If there exists some $x \in q_1(U_i) \cap q_1(U_j)$, say $x = q_1(e_i) = q_1(e_j)$, then there is some $\varphi \in \text{Aut}_{q_1}(E)$ such that $e_i = \varphi(e_j)$ because $q_1$ is a normal covering. Since $\varphi \in \text{Aut}_{q_2}(E)$, it follows that $U_i = \varphi(U_j)$ by Proposition 12.1(c) (If $q : E \to X$ is a covering map and $U\subseteq X$ is an evenly covered open subset, then each covering automorphism permutes the components of $q^{-1}(U)$), and hence $q_1(U_i) = q_1(\varphi(U_j)) = q_1(U_j)$. That is, $q_1(U_i)$ and $q_1(U_j)$ are either equal or disjoint. By the definition of $q$ we have that $q^{-1}(U) = q_1(q_2^{-1}(U))$. It follows that
$$
        q^{-1}(U) \setminus q_1(U_i) = \bigcup_{q_1(U_j) \neq q_1(U_i)} q_1(U_j),
$$
so $q_1(U_i)$ is open and closed in $q^{-1}(U)$ (using that each $U_j$ is open in $E$ and $q_1$ is an open map). Since $q_1(U_i)$ is connected, we have that $q_1(U_i)$ is a component of $q^{-1}(U)$. Moreover, all of the components of $q^{-1}(U)$ are equal to $q_1(U_j)$ for some (not unique) component $U_j$ of $q_2^{-1}(U)$.

Let $q_1|_{U_i} : U_i \to q_1(U_i)$, $q_2|_{U_i} : U_i \to U$, and $q|_{q_1(U_i)} : q_1(U_i) \to U$ be the restrictions. We have that $q_1|_{U_i}$ is open, continuous, and surjective. Since $q|_{q_1(U_i)} \circ q_1|_{U_i} = q_2|_{U_i}$ is a homeomorphism, $q_1|_{U_i}$ is injective, hence a homeomorphism. It then follows that $q|_{q_1(U_i)}$ is a homeomorphism. Thus $q$ restricts to a homeomorphism on the components of $q^{-1}(U)$, so $U$ is evenly covered by $q$.